What can I do about this error, "Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again."
My computer, which was running fine just a day ago, now will not boot Steam nor my VPN (PrivateVPN).
When starting Steam I get an error that says:

"Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again."

When I attempt to log into my VPN, I get a message that says "API Error" and "getAuth."
I think these two things may be connected to some sort of network problem that is out of my knowledge. My Steam log is pasted below:
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Startup - updater built May 20 2024 14:26:54
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Startup - Steam Client launched with: "G:\Steam\steam.exe" 
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] 1. https://cdn.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Verifying installation...
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Unable to read and verify install manifest G:\Steam\package\steam_client_win32.installed
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Verification complete
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Downloading update...
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Checking for available updates...
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Downloading manifest: https://cdn.steamstatic.com/client/steam_client_win32
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Manifest download: send request
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Manifest download: waiting for download to finish
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Manifest download: finished
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Download failed: http error 0 (cdn.steamstatic.com/client/steam_client_win32)
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] DownloadManifest - exhausted list of download hosts
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] failed to load manifest from buffer.
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Failed to load manifest
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Error: Download failed: http error 0
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Saving metrics to disk (G:\Steam\package\steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2024-07-12 17:10:21] Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again.
[2024-07-12 17:10:23] Shutdown

Here's the results of pinging steam as well:
Pinging cdn.steamstatic.com [23.47.48.152] with 32 bytes of data: Reply from 23.47.48.152: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=53 Reply from 23.47.48.152: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=53 Reply from 23.47.48.152: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53 Reply from 23.47.48.152: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53 Ping statistics for 23.47.48.152: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: Minimum = 33ms, Maximum = 34ms, Average = 33ms

I have tried updating my router firmware, reinstalling Steam, and changing my registry settings. I also ran netsh winhttp reset proxy in admin mode on my command prompt. The result was "Direct access (no proxy server)."
Just in case this is relevant, I have an ethernet cable connected to my modem.

Your machine isn’t connected to the internet based on those error messages

I'm currently talking to you on the same computer that I'm having problems on.

Can you ping cdn.steamstatic.com? The fact you can’t connect to Steam nor your VPN suggests a configuration problem.

Sure, I just pinged it. Here's the results:
Pinging cdn.steamstatic.com [23.47.48.152] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 23.47.48.152: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=53
Reply from 23.47.48.152: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=53
Reply from 23.47.48.152: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 23.47.48.152: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Ping statistics for 23.47.48.152:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 33ms, Maximum = 34ms, Average = 33ms

Ping isn’t all that relevant though. Try doing what Steam is trying to do: Download https://cdn.steamstatic.com/client/steam_client_win32 (it’s a text file). Does that work? Did you set an unusable proxy in Windows or Steam?

Alrighty, I downloaded the file and tried to run Steam to no avail, then tried moving the file into the Steam folder and tried again. Neither of these things worked. As far as the proxy goes, I don't know how to use proxies so I generally don't mess with them. Would there be a way to reset my proxy settings to default in case that is the problem?
